# How to ignore htaccess folder from wordpress htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file in Wordpress. It's located at /file_name/ (web root). I need to exclude a folder (booknow) from the rewrite engine.

I've tried this code:

```
RewriteRule ^/booknow($|/) - [L]
```

My Full `.htaccess` code given below:

```
#BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /file_now/
    RewriteRule ^/booknow($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /file_now/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

I tried this code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own answer. I create a `.htaccess` File in WordPress directory booknow folder then I added below code to `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{file_now/booknow} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /file_now/booknow/404page.php
```

Now My Booknow folder is properly working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(directory_name)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly assuming the br in your code are mistakes and not that you're writing HTML inside a .htaccess file.

The pattern in your rewrite rule has both a slash in the RewriteBase and the RewriteRule, so it's looking for something like /file_name//booknow/ You should instead type:

```
RewriteRule ^booknow($|/) - [L]
```

Comment: Here `file_now` is the main wordpress directory